# Is there any benefit to running docker containers on different Amazon servers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

If I've built a microservices-based web app, is there any benefit to running docker containers on separate servers?  When I say servers, I mean each with it's own OS, Kernel, etc.

One obvious benefit would be that if that machine goes down, it wouldn't take down all the services, but other than this what are the benefits?

Also, does Elastic Beanstalk ALREADY do this?  or does it just deploy the containers on a single machine sharing the kernel (similar to Docker on a local machine).

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about a clustered solution. That's running your services on multiple nodes (hosts).

The benefits are High Availability (no single point of failure) and Scalability; you can spread the load across multiple nodes and you can increase/decrease the number of nodes as needed to accomodate usage. All of these need to be taken care of when you design your application.

Nowadays, all the major cloud providers have proprietary technologies to cover clustering. You can use AWS's Elastic Beanstalk to create your clustered solution based on Docker containers as the building blocks. However you lock yourself in with AWS's technologies. I prefer to rely entirely on open source technologies (eg: Docker Swarm, Kubernetes) for clustering so that I can deploy to both on-premises data centers and different cloud solutions (AWS, Azure, GCP).

Comment: I guess my question is are services A and B (both running from Docker containers) sharing a kernel when deployed  to Elastic Beanstalk, or are they running on different machines.

Comment: Elastic Beanstalk gives you both options. You can run your service on a single host or on multiple hosts (nodes) using EC2 Container Service as the clustering technology. Docker containers share the kernel of the host on which they are running.